# Entity Framework update database from console app

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is there a way to update database from a code-first project by means of C# code?

What I need is writing C# code and launch it (console application) and the app does the `update-database` for me instead of me typing `update-database` in command window of Visual Studio.

Thanks

Comment: what sort of "update" you want to do to the database ?

Comment: Let's say I've changed a model and added a field so I need to update database using update-database command

Comment: Are you trying to implement Automatically Upgrading on Application Startup (MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion Initializer) as per this link? 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx#Automatically%20Upgrading%20on%20Application%20Startup%20(MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion%20Initializer)

Comment: Yes that's what I need but problem is I don't want to run **Run the Update-Database –Verbose command in Package Manager Console** i need to some how run this code directly using my console app in c# code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
var configuration = new Configuration();
var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
//Update database to latest migration
migrator.Update();
```